# Bounded Brownian Bridge

Tags: brownian-motion, expectation

I am trying to calculate the following expectation value of

$$
E[exp(-\int_{t_0}^{t_1} X_s ds)]
$$
in which Xs is a bounded Brownian bridge, which means $X(t_0)=a$, $X(t_1)=b$ and $A<X(t)<B$. Could somebody please help me?

Comment: Please define "bounded Brownian bridge".

Comment: Do you know the answer when $X$ is not bounded?